# Variable defined in subscription is undefined outside (Angular2, Firebase)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

In my Angular2 component **constructor** I store a value from Firebase into a variable.

```
this.dbAction.getDB().take(1).subscribe(data => {
  this.userVisitOrder = data[0][this.currentUserID]['settings']['visitOrder']; 
  console.log(this.userVisitOrder); // Value exists
});
```

I need exactly that variable to build my Observable to use specific firebase data. Also in my constructor:

```
this.visitsRef = afDatabase.list('data/users/' + this.currentUserID + '/visits/', ref => ref.orderByChild(this.userVisitOrder)); // Here the value is undefined
```

I think that´s an async issue, but how can I access the data stored in my variable?

The `getDb()`function in my `dbAction` Service looks like that:

```
getDB() {
  return this.afDatabase.list(`data`).valueChanges().map((data) => data);
}
```

**And if I try to put the second code into the first like that:**

```
this.dbAction.getDB().take(1).subscribe(data => {
  this.userVisitOrder = data[0][this.currentUserID]['settings']['visitOrder'];

  this.visitsRef = afDatabase.list('data/users/' + this.currentUserID + '/visits/', ref => ref.orderByChild(this.userVisitOrder));
  this.visits = this.visitsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
  });
});
```

... I get the following console error:

[image]

Comment: The first situation definitely seems to be async.  You can't access the return from .subscribe outside the block.  The second issue seems like .getDB() isn't defined for some reason.  Hard to tell for sure from this snippet how that would be.  (i.e. you are not ever getting to execute the .subscribe.)

Comment: I edited my post with the `getDb()` helper function from my service. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the observables together with [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) so one runs after the other.

```
this.dbAction.getDB().take(1)
    .switchMap(data => {
        this.userVisitOrder = data[0][this.currentUserID]['settings']['visitOrder'];

        this.visitsRef = afDatabase.list('data/users/' + this.currentUserID + '/visits/', ref => ref.orderByChild(this.userVisitOrder));

        return this.visitsRef.snapshotChanges();
    })
    .map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
    .subscribe(res => {// do something with result})
```

Comment: Where do I declare `this.visits` for the Observable I call in my view?

Comment: @eleinad ah are you using it with an async pipe in your html?

Comment: @eleinad ah ok I misunderstood the question. What you have should work, the async pipe wont subscribe to `this.visits` until it is defined in `this.dbAction.getDB().take(1).subscribe`. The error you are getting says `this.dbAction.getDB()` is undefined, but I am unsure how its undefined

Comment: @eleinad try moving your code into ngOnInit instead of the constructor

Comment: I found the issue! I had `this.visits.subscribe( () => this.spinner = false );` in my `ngOnInit`, because of async `this.visits` was still undefined. Moving this line into the `this.dbAction.getDB().subscribe` make it works! Many thanks for your help! :)